# Meteor.js Iron Routing :_id dynamic route confusion

Tags: meteor, routes, iron-router

I'm currently working my way though "Your Second Meteor Application" and have been enjoying it so far. Everything I have created works but I do not understand why the following works but the code at the end does not.

**Template**

```
<template name="list">
  <ul>
    {{#each list}}
      <li><a href="/list/{{_id}}">{{name}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="listPage">
  <h2>Tasks: {{name}}</h2>
</template>
```

**Route**

```
Router.route('/list/:_id', {
  template: 'listPage',
  data: function(){
    var currentList = this.params._id;
    return Lists.findOne({_id: currentList});
  }
});
```

This is giving the expected results. However, I was curious why the following will not work as it seems to be passing the exact same thing. The only differences with the following are:

- changing the Router.route('lists/:_id') to Router.route('lists/randomParm')
- this.params._id to this.params.randomParm

**Template**

```
<template name="list">
  <ul>
    {{#each list}}
      <li><a href="/list/{{_id}}">{{name}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="listPage">
  <h2>Tasks: {{name}}</h2>
</template>
```

**Route**

```
Router.route('/list/randomParm', {
  template: 'listPage',
  data: function(){
    var currentList = this.params.randomParm;
    return Lists.findOne({_id: currentList});
  }
});
```

The message I am getting is:

> Oops, looks like there's no route on the client or the server for url: "http://localhost:3000/list/TGM9dbRRtspyJy7AR."

Isn't :_id and randomParm holding the same values? An id of list items from the HTML links that are being passed to the routing url and being used to make a mongo call? I don't quite understand how :_id and randomParm are different when I am hitting the same routing URL.

Answer (score 3):

Param shold be with `:`

So your route will be

```
Router.route('/list/:randomParm', {
```

If this param is optional then leave `?` after

```
Router.route('/list/:randomParm?', {
```